# Find the equation of the tangent and normal to the curve $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$ at $x = 1$.

Tags: calculus

I got the same answer for both the tangent and the normal but according to the book I'm using,  I'm wrong.

I used 
$$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1).$$

I got the gradient for the tangent as $0$ and the gradient for the normal would be the negative reciprocal, right which would remain $0$. So I'm getting the same answer.

Comment: what did you get/do?

Comment: Tangent and normal are perpendicular. If you have one, you don't even need to bother finding the other.

Comment: Can you show your workings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $x=1$, we have $y=2$. The derivative of $y$ is $y'=1-1/x^2$. Hence, at $x=1$, the gradient is $m=y'(1)=1-1=0$. The equation $y=mx+c$ gives $y=c$ since $m=0$, which given the point $(1,2)$ means that $y=2$. Any normal to a horizontal line must be a vertical line $x=d$, and given the point $(1,2)$ we must have $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

We can get that answer without actually differentiating the function. We know that, 
$$x + \frac {1}{x} \geq 2$$ with equality holding at $x = 1$. Now, the function $x + \frac {1}{x}$ is continuous and differentiable for all $x \gt 0$ and we see that at $x=1$ the function attains a minimum. So the derivative at $x=1$ must be zero. So we have our tangent equation $y=2$ and to its perpendicular the normal equation is $x=1$.

CAUTION : There is no such thing as $\frac {1}{0}$(And specially $\frac {1}{0} \neq 0$). The slope of the normal is the negative of the reciprocal of that of the tangent iff the slope of the tangent is defined and $\neq 0$. The real thing is that they are perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have $y'(1) = 0$, and $y(1) = 2$, so the tangent is $y =2$. The normal is $x = 1$. One line is vertical, the other horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the gradient of the normal at a point on a curve, is equal to the negative reciprocal of the gradient of the tangent, at that same point on the curve.

For example, if the gradient of the tangent is 0.5, then the gradient of the normal would be -1/0.5 which is equal to -2.

Consequently it's not possible in this case for the normal gradient to be equal to the tangent gradient.